# How to extract the data from a firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication

I need to obtain data of the user who is logging in. I use firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged to see if the user is logged in and I console.log the userData returned.

It returns all the user's data, see below, but I cannot find how to retrieve it. I can retrieve userData.email, userData.fullname and userData.uid which I know come from the authorization but the other data is there. I know I could use the uid to read the data agaib but it is already there.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

confirm:"new"
email:"yakr@uacro.com"
fullname:"john Varified"
paytype:"d"
registrationDate:"Sat Sep 23 2017"
theme:"grey"
uid:"FWOb7eJ38veRXQ7wadk77YzhyMj1"

Comment: Sorry I did not see your reply until this morning. I have saved the user to the firebase db and retrieved it using firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged. In a console log I can see all the data (see at the bottom of the original question). userData.email ect retrieves "email", "fullname" and "uid" but  not "confirm", "paytype", "registrationDate" or "theme". Console.log can retrieve them why can't I?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Essential Courses on Udemy.com I found my missing link. I needed a service to set and destroy a local image.

```
export class User2memoryService {

  constructor() {}

  set(userFromDb) {
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(userFromDb));
  }

  destroy() {
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
  }
}
```